# How to run one instance of a job at one time in QuartZ?

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net-3.0

I want to implement the `Quartz.Net` in my C#.Net project. I am syncing 1 FTP and downloading all file every 10 minutes. Once I downloaded every file, I am going to process them all. If there are be more files, it will take more time than 10 minutes.

How to run 1 instance of a job and, if the trigger sets off any another job instance, it should not run and dispose it?

My Code:

Quartz Scheduler Class

```
public class ResponseFileSyncJobScheduler
{
    public static async Task StartResponsefileSyncker()
    {
        ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler sched = await sf.GetScheduler();

        //DateTimeOffset runTime = DateBuilder.EvenMinuteDate(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ResponseFileJob>()
            .WithIdentity("ResponsefileSync", "sgroup")
            .Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("TriggerfileSync", "sgroup")
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
            (s => s.WithIntervalInMinutes(10).OnEveryDay())
            .StartAt(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1))
            .Build();

        await sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        await sched.Start();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(65));
    }
}
```

Quartz Job Class

```
public class QuartzJobSOGET : IJob
{
    internal static readonly Task CompletedTask = Task.FromResult(true);

    public virtual Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        JobKey jobKey = context.JobDetail.Key;

        //Write Date Time to File - to ensure Quartz Scheduler Working   
        WritetoFile(DateTime.Now.ToString());

        //Sync every present file and process 
        //once processed delete file from server and make log, 
        //will take 1 min to process single file (almost)
        SyncResponseFilefromSOGETftp();

        return CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest, you set a bool value to true, when you start the job, then when a new job comes in you check if the old job is still running.

Comment: @PoulBak Agreed 100%, keep it simple

Comment: Hi @PoulBak, There is no such step I could use this. Quartz has a machinism to start the class itself and use the memory management. How could I even suppose to do so??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a long time, I found the answer earlier, but could not able to post here.

We can use the `DisallowConcurrentExecution` Attribute over the class to stop multiple executions of the single job.

Reference : [Job State and Concurrency](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html)

However, you can also check out this link for Git-Issue: (could be useful) [@DisallowConcurrentExecution misinterpretation on clustered Scheduler](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/issues/117)